# Create ISO image from folder

Tags: macos, directory, iso

I wrote a script which creates and ISO image from a folder, but when the folder contains spaces, I get an error message. Can somebody please help me? I'm working with Mac OSX Mavericks and Terminal.

Thanks in advance.

Script:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /Volumes/Daten/fake
for i in ./*; do hdiutil makehybrid -udf -joliet -iso -o /Volumes/Daten/test/$i ./*;done
```

error:

```
hdiutil: makehybrid: multiple sources specified
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use double-quotes around all variable references (e.g. `"$i"`) to prevent word splitting. BTW, it also looks like your script will fail if there's more than one item in /Volumes/Daten/fake, because the `./*` at the end of the hdiutil command will try to include *all* of the items in each image, which will also fail. Finally, `./*` is generally unnecessary; just use `*`. I think you want this:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /Volumes/Daten/fake
for i in *; do
    hdiutil makehybrid -udf -joliet -iso -o "/Volumes/Daten/test/$i" "$i"
done
```

Answer (score 2):

Launch disk utility and select new>blank disk image from folder... It's as simple as that!

Comment: Yes, simple. Unless it tries for a while to make that image, then fails with `Operation failed: Operation not permitted`. This is what I'm getting on creating an image from a user home dir.